# Input property bindings picks up the change only after timeout

Tags: angular, angular9, property-binding

I am working on a template wherein I have a child component to display the detailed information of the parent. There is a service call that pulls the data of a list of items and then processes it. However, the data required for the child component is already available in the parent's controller.

I am using mat-expansion panel (from Angular material: https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview) to build the UI for the parent component and to show the detailed description of the item (child component).

The issue that I am facing is that, I am using *(opened)* event emitter from mat-expansion-panel to update the bindings of the data that is being forwarded to the child. When the user clicks on the expansion panel a method is called to extract the data, and then the second service is called to merge some data, and then it is being sent to the child component to render. The issue that I am facing is that the values are not getting updated in the child component though the parent is forwarding it properly. But, if I use the timeout then the binding update on the view.

The first bound data will be shown first which is as expected, but the second item data when expanded will still show the first item data.

Below is the parent component:

```
<mat-accordion *ngFor="let item of items">
    <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="getItemDetails()">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            {{item.name}}
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    </mat-expansion-panel>

    <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
        <child-component *ngIf="dataToDisplay" [dataToDisplay]="dataToDisplay"></child-component>
    </ng-template>
</mat-accordion>
```

Parent Controller:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent-component',
    templateUrl: './parent.component.html'
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
    items: any = [];
    dataToDisplay: any;

    constructor(private myService: MyService, private mySecondService: MySecondService){}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.myService.getItems().pipe(take(1)).subscribe((response) => {
             this.items = response;
        });
    }

    getItemDetails(item): void {
        if (this.items) {
            this.mySecondService.getMergedData(item).pipe(take(1)).subscribe((response) => {
                // the below code update the child component bindings
                this.dataToDisplay = {
                     emailId: response.emailId,
                     phoneNumber: response.phoneNumber
                };

                // the same code works when placed inside setTimeout
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.dataToDisplay = {
                       emailId: response.emailId,
                       phoneNumber: response.phoneNumber
                    };
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Child Component:

```
<div>
    <p>{{dataToDisplay.emailId}}</p>
    <p>{{dataToDisplay.phoneNumber}}</p>
</div>
```

Child controller:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child-component',
    templateUrl: './child.component.html'
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input
    dataToDisplay: any;
}
```

Please let me know if there are any issues with the code or if there is any workaround. Thanks.